# Root of website in a subdirectory in PHP

Tags: php, path, subdirectory

I'm developing a website in PHP.
The test environment is in a subdirectory of the root and there are multiple test environments. But the website doesn't work properly because of al the absolute and also the relative paths.
So i need a clean solution to get the path of the root of the website and not of the server.

I've tried a lot of thinks but nothing seems to work.

I hope you have a beter solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to be more specific for us being able to help you. What are the lot of things have you tried? What type of error do you get?

Comment: What server are you on, Apache? Can you create a subdomain, pointing at the subdir?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but if you want to get directory of current php file you should use `__DIR__` constant. More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

If your website index is located at /home/www/subpath/index.php, this code in index.php:

```
echo __DIR__;
```

will return:

```
/var/www/subpath
```

Comment: but this won't easily help in static files such as css

Comment: Is this question about path to files on server or url path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SESSION to set your desired PATH and use it on all the path you need.

If you are using a framework like Laravel this can be done a lot easier.